# my code says "Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first"

Tags: python-3.7, pyaudio

My code says "Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first"

```
import speech_recognition as sr
for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone name: \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
```

Comment: How did you install it and what version of python are you using ?